# Django QuerySet Custom Ordering by ID

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Given a list of ids/pks, I'd like to generate a `QuerySet` of objects ordered by the index in the list.

Normally I'd begin with:

```
pk_list = [5, 9, 2, 14]
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list)
```

This of course returns the objects, but in the order of the models meta ordering property, and I wish to get the records in the order of the `pk`s in `pk_list`.

The end result has to be *one* `QuerySet` object (not a list), as I wish to pass the ordered `QuerySet` to Django's `ModelMultipleChoiceField` form field.

Comment: At db level for MySQL & PostgreSQL: http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/django-create-a-queryset-from-a-list-preserving-order.html

Comment: As of Django >= 1.11 you could do it like i suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966462/sort-queryset-by-values-in-list/52224856#52224856

Answer (score 11):

There isn't a built-in way to do this.

If you're using MySQL, you can use that database's `FIELD()` function to set up a custom ordering sequence on your model, and sort by that. This would work:

```
pk_list = [5, 9, 2, 14]
ordering = 'FIELD(`id`, %s)' % ','.join(str(id) for id in pk_list)
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=[pk_list]).extra(
               select={'ordering': ordering}, order_by=('ordering',))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I need something which will be compatible with both sqlite and mysql. I think i'll go with using `MultipleChoiceField` and generating the list of choices myself.

Comment: @amirouche, no he wants it in an order altogether different than simple numerical sort.

Answer (score 5):

In **Django 2.2**, I was able to order QuerySet based on an order list using following approach:

```
pk_list = [4, 23, 10, 9]
preserved = Case(*[When(pk=pk, then=pos) for pos, pk in enumerate(pk_list)])
new_qs = qs.filter(pk__in=pk_list).order_by(preserved)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a way to do this using a filter condition. If your database will return the rows in the order of the `IN` clause then you *may* be able to combine Django's `extra` method with the `ROWNUM` provided by your database to achieve this.

For e.g.:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=[pk_list]).extra(
       select: {'rownum': 'row_num()'}).order_by('rownum')
```

Where `row_num()` is assumed to be a database function that returns the row number of the current row. Postgresql 8.4+ supports `row_num()` but I do not know how to order the rows returned using the same order as the values in the `IN` clause.

I think a better way would be to sub class `ModelMultipleChoiceField` and add custom sorting logic when rendering.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I need something which will be compatible with both sqlite and mysql. I think i'll go with using `MultipleChoiceField` and generating the list of choices myself.