# Sort queryset by values in list

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to sort a django queryset by the list of elements provided in the query?
For example, if I do

```
m.objects.filter(id__in=[3,1,8])
```

I wan't the order of the queryset to be the element of id 3, the element of id 1 and the element of id 8.

Thanks

Comment: I asked the same question awhile back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625641/django-queryset-custom-ordering-by-id, and unfortunately there is no database agnostic way of doing it.

Comment: Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361243/django-in-query-lookup-doesnt-maintain-the-order-in-queryset/70830205#70830205

Answer (score 12):

Since there exists `Case` and `When` in Django >= 1.11 you can do it in a more orm-like way keeping all the benefits of your queryset:

```
from django.db import models

order = ['b', 'a', 'z', 'x', 'c']
_whens = []

for sort_index, value in enumerate(order):
    _whens.append(
        models.When(my_field=value, then=sort_index)
    )

qs = MyModel.objects.annotate(
        _sort_index=models.Case(
            *_whens, 
            output_field=models.IntegerField()
        )
     )

qs.order_by('_sort_index')
```

This will generate something like this:

```
from django.db import models

order = ['b', 'a', 'z', 'x', 'c']
qs = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    _sort_index=models.Case(
        models.When(my_field='b', then=0),
        models.When(my_field='a', then=1),
        models.When(my_field='z', then=2),
        models.When(my_field='x', then=3),
        models.When(my_field='c', then=4),
        output_field=models.IntegerField()
    )
).order_by('_sort_index')
```

I would suggest to use this only with a small amount of list-items because it blows up the database-query.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case

Answer (score 5):

No. There is no way to do what you want short of some contrived mechanism like:

```
qs = m.objects.filter(id__in=[3,1,8])
qs_sorted = list()
for id in [3,1,8]:
    qs_sorted.append(qs.get(id=id))
```

You'd need to throw some exception handling in there as well, just in case one of the specified ids wasn't actually returned.

The negatives are that this will effectively negate the lazy loading of queryset. In fact, it's very likely to generate multiple DB queries (haven't tested that though). Also, you end up with a normal python list instead of a queryset, so no more filtering is possible.

Comment: I know that. That's why I hoped that a simpler solution would exist.

Comment: Sorry, no. Even if Django *had* a mechanism, it would have to use the same process to produce the results. Arbitrary sorts aren't supported at the database level in any database I know of.

Comment: if queryset is big, it will be slow to get every element by id

Answer (score 5):

```
_list = [3,1,2]
sorted(queryset, key=lambda x: _list.index(x.id))
```

Comment: nice neat and clean solution

Answer (score 3):

See [Ordering by the order of values in a SQL IN() clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause) - you'd need to drop down to a [raw queryset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) and it'd be database specific.

If you're using MySQL for example you should be able to do a

```
Model.objects.raw('select * from myapp_model where id in (3,1,8) order by field(id,3,1,8)')
```

Comment: your solution seems great but i'm using postgresql and it's not trivial to do that query in it.

Comment: See the post by pilcrow over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql for some pg functions

Answer (score 2):

Most of your sorting options assume there is an *order* to what you are sorting. If you can define the order you can use `order_by` and a field on your model, or `sorted` using python. If you want to just reorder things (with seemingly no logic) you could still probably use `sorted`:

```
for id in [3,1,8]:
    sorted(qs, key=lambda x: x.id == id)
```

Comment: But with order_by I need to specify a model field right? Or I can just give a list as a paramter?

Comment: @Vitor how are you coming up with this ordering? It seems pretty arbitrary. You could use my approach to sort them w/o extra database hits, but it seems like the better approach would be to rethink your models, and introduce a field which will allow you to sort the instances in the order you desire. Or refactor somehow so the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Is this doing a sort for EACH id? So as N increases it's doing N searches, and saying a search is N log N, so this becomes a O(N^2)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use order-by as zeekay mentioned.

If it is OK that your QuerSet will be turned into a list, then you can use something like this

```
sorted(queryset, key=lambda x: x.id)
```

Comment: yes, but that just orders the queryset in the same way as qs.order_by('id'). I wan't to maintain the order I gave in the list, [3,1,8].

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your answers. I'v came up with another solution. It's not the best one but is only needs to do one query to the database.
I have a list with the id's I want ordered by my needs. Then I make the query and fill in a dictionary with the data and finally I traverse l picking up the objects in an ordered fashion.

```
l =[7,1,4]
p_dict = {}
p = Poi.objects.filter(id__in=l)
for i in p:
    p_dict[i.id] = i
```

Using this I will use a lot of memory right? But I gain in accesses to the database.

@a-lee I will investigate your solution and try to tranform it to postgresql.

Comment: This is exactly what Django's built-in `p_dict = Poi.objects.in_bulk([7, 1, 4])` would do.

Answer (score -1):

```
preserved = [Case(*[When(pk=pk, then=pos) for pos, pk in enumerate([3,1,8])])]
queryset.order_by(*preserved)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include an explanation with your answer to help readers understand how this works, and solves the problem. You can click the edit button at the bottom of your answer to add an explanation. Additionally, have a read of [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)