# Ordering filtered queryset according to a order of list

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filter

I have a list described below.
I want a queryset which will be ordered according to the order of list

### list

```
 id_list = [3,1,2]
```

### queryset

```
   queryset = Variant.objects.filter(pk__in=id_list)
```

the queryset gives objects in the order below:

```
obj1
obj2
obj3
```

but i want the objects according to order in the given list:

```
obj3
obj1
obj2
```

how??

Comment: Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361243/django-in-query-lookup-doesnt-maintain-the-order-in-queryset/70830205#70830205

Answer (score 1):

Don't define ordering in code - add ordering column to your table and order by it. That's it.

```
class Variant(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField()
    ...

Variant(ordering=3).save() # id == 1
Variant(ordering=1).save() # id == 2
Variant(ordering=2).save() # id == 3

queryset = Variant.objects.filter(pk__in=id_list).order_by('order')
```

So you will have queryset according to desirable order.

Otherwise google: django convert list to queryset and use Sayse answer as base for your code.
One example: [django - convert a list back to a queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058135/django-convert-a-list-back-to-a-queryset)

Comment: thaks for your answer. But I need this for a certain case.

Comment: You should show how this would apply to the op's question. I'm pretty sure that there isn't any way to order a querysets results based upon a python array

Comment: I've updated my answer. But be sure if you define queryset order by database object id in the code - something wrong with architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could do this with a queryset (nor do I understand why you want to...)

You could do it with a map, but be warned, this will resolve the query and be potentially inefficient.

```
variants = list(map(lambda id: Variant.objects.get(pk=id), id_list))
```

Comment: hey Sayse,
thanks for your answer.
I can do the thing you described but it gives me a list.
I want the queryset as I need more filter on that queryset later.

Comment: @cjahangir - It doesn't make sense to order a queryset, the order in which they're evaluated shouldn't have any effect on what you're trying to do