# How to query list while preserving order

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I wanted to do a query based on a list. I know I can do this:

```
lists = [Everton, Liverpool, Villa]
queryset = Betting.objects.filter(matches__in=list)
```

However, this doesnt query the table in order. The operation am doing is based on [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) and is vital the query is done in order of the list

I have seen this solution [django-create-a-queryset-from-a-list-preserving-order.html](http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/django-create-a-queryset-from-a-list-preserving-order.html) but it doesnt seem to work with sqllite

Thanks..Any help will be appreciated

Comment: ORM table to be queried in order of the list..ie..It checks first for list[0], list[1] and the rest in order of how they appear in the list

Comment: Could you specify what exact order are you looking for?

Comment: Do you really need a queryset? If not you could just python sort after the query.

Comment: Yes I need a queryset, so as to be able to get other field attributes..eg book.date or book.author..To do this I need a queryset

Comment: btw, raw SQL is always a solution in this kind of stuck

Comment: Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361243/django-in-query-lookup-doesnt-maintain-the-order-in-queryset/70830205#70830205

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When, IntegerField

cases = [When(matches=x, then=Value(i)) for i,x in enumerate(lists)] 
case = Case(*cases, output_field=IntegerField())
queryset = Betting.objects.filter(matches__in=lists)
queryset = queryset.annotate(my_order=case).order_by('my_order')
```

Comment: Thanks ..but  what is     'output_field=IntegerField()'

Comment: `from django.db.models import IntegerField` , to store the output of the case check

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure of efficiency, but it can be a way

```
lists = [Everton, Liverpool, Villa]
queryset = Betting.objects.all()
for i in lists:
    queryset = queryset.filter(matches=i)
```

The reason you can do is that if you do, queryset.filter(some condition).filter(some other condition), then the result is actually the union of both filters in their order