# How can I create a dictionary of two lists that preserves the order of the first list in the minimum number of queries?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-queryset

Let's say that I have a list of movie ids in a QuerySet in the following format:

```
movie_ids = [12,4,9,16]
```

Now, I want to pull the list of corresponding movies.  I also want to minimize the number of queries.  So I do the following:

```
movies = Movie.objects.filter(pk__in=movie_ids)
```

However, this query won't guarantee that movies will have the corresponding movie objects in the same order as they were in movie_ids, will it?  Is there anyway to guarantee the order (so that each movie_id corresponds to the correct movie) so I can do something pair the two lists into a dictionary with:

```
id_movies = dict(zip(movie_ids, movies))
```

This would then be used in my template in Django.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django QuerySet Custom Ordering by ID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625641/django-queryset-custom-ordering-by-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dict like

```
# Create the dict for the movies object.
id_movies = dict([(m.id, m) for m in movies])

# Get the data in order.
order_movies = [id_movies[i] for i in movie_ids]
```

This way you will get the object in same order which you gave.

Comment: Now we're first creating the list and from that the dict. Is there any reason to not go with `{m.id : m for m in movies}` which does the same (?) thing inline?