# Ordering the display items by row-id in Django-Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a table of static data, loaded via initial_data.json.  The admin interface apparently displays the data ordered by descending pk; i.e. the records with the largest pk are at the top of list.  I would like to reverse this, ideally by using the pk value.  Since it's static data, I could add another column for the sort order, but that would essentially duplicate the pk values, or I could, when generating my fixture file, use "pk=len(data)-i" instead of the "pk=i" that I'm currently using.  But really, I'd like to just say something like this:

```
class DataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('row_id',)
```

I've tried using 'row_id', 'id', and 'pk', without success.  Does anyone have any ideas beffore I go source-diving?  Thanks!

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625641/django-queryset-custom-ordering-by-id

Comment: Hi! **it work** for me with "ordering = ('id')" in the model admin... (using django 2.4 and python 2.7). I think it should be ordering= ('pk',) and that may be a django improvement idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put the [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) on the actual model in its Meta class

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['pk']
```

Comment: That does exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: When trying this in Django 1.10 with Python 3, this solution gives me the id of the model pointed to by the Through model, rather than the Through model's own `pk`.